# How to access CSS Style Rules of MenuBar from Code - GWT

Tags: java, html, css, gwt

Is there a way to edit a custom css class of mind to enable these css style rules
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html

I currenly created my MenuBar through code like :

```
        MenuBar menuButton = new MenuBar();         
        menuButton.addStyleName(masterPanel.getmenuBar());
```

Using the interface to get the css class:

```
interface Style extends CssResource {
        String menuBar();
        String action();
    }
```

I have a css class that can ONLY edit my menu bar:

```
.menuBar {
cursor: default; 
text-align: center;
background: transparent;
border: none;
color: white;
text-shadow: none;
font-size: 16px;    
}
```

Is there a way i can access styles like:

```
.gwt-MenuBar-horizontal
.gwt-MenuBar-vertical
.gwt-MenuBar .gwt-MenuItem
.gwt-MenuBar .gwt-MenuItem-selected
.gwt-MenuBar .gwt-MenuItemSeparator
.gwt-MenuBar .gwt-MenuItemSeparator .menuSeparatorInner
.gwt-MenuBarPopup .menuPopupTopLeft
```

Answer (score 1):

First i added your css snippet to the .css of the project and added it to the menu bar with `menuButton.setStyleName("menuBar")`. Then i added the following to the project css class (as an example) :

```
.gwt-MenuItem-selected 
{
color:red !important; 
}
```

Now the first menuBar style is enabled and the additional style is set, too. Its necessary  to use the !important to override the default properties.

Comment: Does it still work, if my css is located in a UiBiner xml file ?